# NSTextView and Core Animation drawing trouble

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nstextview

I'm having some trouble adding CA Layers on top of a NSTextView. I want to be able to add small "bubbles" (like in Xcode) to the text view, so i thought of doing it with core animation. When i enable layer backed mode in the views -awakeFromNib `[self wantsLayer:YES]`, and add a empty CALayer as root layer `[self setLayer:rootLayer]`, the content of the view gets completely destroyed with random garbage

[image: Random garbage]

If I set a background color on the root layer, that color shows nicely up. So somehow the textview behind the transparent layer doesnt redraw? Or is it a different problem?

**EDIT:** 
[Here is an example project producing something similair](http://halfdanj.dk/files/LayberBackedTextView.zip)  (at least on 10.8)

Jonas

Comment: Can you share some code (maybe the method where you add associate the layer with the view)??

Comment: I've edited the post with a link to a zip containing a project that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that you can't replace the layer of the NSTextView, but only add sub layers. So replacing the line `self.layer = rootLayer` with `[self.layer addSubLayer:rootLayer]` works.
Replacing the layer breaks the NSTextView drawing.